# How do I parse custom file with F#?

Tags: file, parsing, f#

I have a custom file which contains data in a format like below

```
prop1: value1
prop2: value2
prop3: value 2

Table Instance 1
A   B  C    D    E
10  11  12  13  14
12  13  11  12  20

Table Instance 2
X  Y  Z
1  3  4
3  4  0

Table Instance 3
P R S
2 3 5
5 5 0
```

I want to be able to parse this file and map the contents to a POCO. I was really excited about working with CSV type provider in F#, but then I quickly realized that it might be not possible to use that in my case. Should I have to write my own parser in this case? (Iterate through each like and parse the values into its appropriate properties in POCO)

Thanks
Kay

Answer (score 1):

If that's a one-of file format, I would just write a parser by hand. Split the file into separate tables, throw away the title and header, then `String.Split` each row and parse the resulting array into a record type specific for the table.

If that file format is more or less standardized and you expect that you'll need to parse it more often and in different contexts (and/or you're feeling adventurous), you can always write your own type provider.